# set() method receiving the value but get() method returning null

Tags: java, null, setter, getter

I am creating a login page which retrieves the user details from the database and stores in the user class.  The Set methods are receiving the values correctly but when I try to access the details using the Get method, it's returning null.  See the code snippets below and can you let me know what exactly I am missing here.

Retrieve details from DB and set the values:

class userdao:

```
user.setID(rs.getString("ID"));
user.setHashPassword(rs.getString("HashPassword"));
user.setAccessLevel(rs.getInt("AccessLevel"));
user.setLastDate(rs.getDate("LastAccessDate"));
```

Note: The connection is closed after this point.

Setting the values:

class user:

```
public class User  
{
    private String ID;
    private String HashPassword;
    private int AccessLEVEL;
    private Date LastAccessDate;

    public User()
    {

    }

    public void setID(String uID) 
    {
        this.ID = uID;
    }    
    public String getID()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }
    public void setHashPassword(String uHash) 
    {
        this.HashPassword = uHash;
    }    
    public String getHashPassword()
    {
        return this.HashPassword;
    }
    public void setAccessLevel(int uALevel) 
    {
        this.AccessLEVEL = uALevel;
    }    
    public int getAccessLevel()
    {
        return this.AccessLEVEL;
    }
    public void setLastDate(Date uLDate) 
    {
        this.LastAccessDate = uLDate;
    }    
    public Date getLastDate()
    {
        return this.LastAccessDate;
    }
}
```

I am accessing the get() values from another class which is receiving the null.

class login:

```
System.out.println(user.getID()); // returning null
System.out.println(user.getHashPassword()); // returning null
System.out.println(user.getAccessLevel()); // returning null
System.out.println(user.getLastDate()); // returning null
```

However, when I create variables in the userdao class (where the DB is returning the details) and call them from the login class, the values return correctly.

Can you help me find out the error in this code?

Here is the complete code of the login and userdao classes.

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    User user = new User();
    static String strUserID;
    static String strPwd;

    public Login()
    {
        super();
        initComponents();
        //JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Login");       
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        PasswordEncrypt cpe = new PasswordEncrypt();
        User user = new User();
        UserDAO uDAO = new UserDAO();

        strUserID = jTextField1.getText();
        char[] pwd = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
        strPwd = new String(pwd);

        if (strUserID.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter The User ID");
            jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        else if (pwd.length == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter The Password");
            jPasswordField1.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Authenticate the User
                String strStoredPwd;
                boolean UserExists;

                uDAO.Authenticate(strUserID);

                strStoredPwd = uDAO.dhash;
                // The following lines are used only when the User class is returning a value
                System.out.println(user.getID());
                System.out.println(user.getHashPassword());
                System.out.println(user.getAccessLevel());
                System.out.println(user.getLastDate());                
                UserExists = cpe.validatePassword(strPwd, strStoredPwd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UserDAO
{
    User user = new User();
    public String dhash;
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;

    // Authenticate Existing User
    public void Authenticate(String UserID) throws SQLException
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = '" + UserID + "'";
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            //Do some thing with rs

            if (rs.next())
            {
                user.setID(rs.getString("ID"));
                user.setHashPassword(rs.getString("HashPassword"));
                user.setAccessLevel(rs.getInt("AccessLevel"));
                user.setLastDate(rs.getDate("LastAccessDate"));                

                dhash = rs.getString("HashPassword");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtil.close(rs);
            DBUtil.close(statement);
            DBUtil.close(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using same object of user in setting and getting the value ??

Comment: How do you know the values are being set?

Comment: I have this statement in both userdao and login classes : User user = new User();

Comment: Are you using Hibernate and spring transactions? I think the session is closed in your dao and when you are accessing in the view you are getting null values. Please check on hibernateSessioninViewFilter examples, by which you can access the hibernate session even in view

Comment: you are using two different objects

Comment: The OP set the value in object so after that if session is closed it will not make any impact.

Comment: You are creating two objects so both will have different states. Setting values in one can't be obtained by other

Comment: #Youngistan - Thanks for pointing that.  How can I use the same object in two different classes?  I am new to Java and learning it for writing an application for a non-profit.

Comment: Just pass the same object in different layer of the project @user3315146

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly using two different objects. Here's how you can test:

In `userdao`, add:

```
System.out.format("userdao: %d%n", System.identityHashCode(user));
```

And in `login`, add the same

```
System.out.format("login: %d%n", System.identityHashCode(user));
```

It is hard to figure out what the exact problem because you haven't pasted the relevant code, but this should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Update the return type of the `Authenticate()` method of class `UserDAO` as

`public User Authenticate(String UserID)` // Return the user object after setting the value

When you call above method from class `Login`,now it will return object of `User` class in which you already sets the value,now code will be updated as below :

```
user = uDAO.Authenticate(strUserID);
```

Comment: @user3315146 added answer,i guess it will work for you